# Composition of a Cadlag function with a Continuous Function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces, continuity

Edited version of question:

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is cadlag (that is, it is right continuous and its left limits exist) and $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Then is it necessarily true that $g\circ f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is also cadlag?

I am trying to prove this more general statement for fun, but I have been quite stuck for a while now.

PS: Currently for what I want to prove all I really need is the weaker statement that $g$ to be the mapping $x\mapsto x^2$. However I am curious whether this more general statement holds as I am sure it will become handy later on/it is in general a useful fact to know.

Many thanks to spaceisdarkgreen for pointing out my horrendous mistake!

Comment: It is easy to show that $g\circ f$ is right continuous, right? because both $f,g$ are right continuous. So you only have to show that the limit from the left exists.

Comment: Yes I gathered that =) But that is precisely where I am getting stuck, showing the left limit exists...

Comment: You mean $f\circ g.$

Comment: Or rather either you mean $f\circ g : \mathbb R\to A$ and it's false (and its falsity has nothing to do with whether $A=\mathbb R$... it's just that if $g$ is decreasing the direction of approach is reversed) or you mean $g\circ f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and it's true cause $g$ preserves limits.

Comment: Actually the latter only makes any sense for $A=\mathbb R,$ so I'm not sure why wrote it down, guess I was still confused.

Comment: Wait sorry ur totally right. I've goofed. Let me think about this question more carefully and edit it!!!

Comment: @user086688 ok then I think my original answer that I deleted applies so I undeleted it. Also to make sure I get pinged when you respond to something, you need to @ me

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you for the answer and your correction and help. I am still kinda new around here and learning the ropes =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For existence of left limits, since $g$ is continuous, we have $$\lim_{x\to a^-} g(f(x)) =g(\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x))$$ and the RHS exists since $f$ is cadlag.

Similarly, for right continuity we have $$\lim_{x\to a^+}g(f(x)) = g(\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)) = g(f(a)).$$